# django form with select fields

Tags: python, django

I have the following models

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

class Subgroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Keywords(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    subgroup = models.ForeignKey(Subgroup)
```

For each Subgroup I need to manage a list of keywords. 
I'm trying to use django forms to automatically display a list (select box) where if I add or remove values to that list and then issue a form.save that it automatically updates the models and data.
How exactly can I do this? Are my models designed properly to allow this?

Comment: Standard HTML selects can't be used for adding or removing values, so you need some JS for handling that. Then override `save` method to accept data passed by JS. May be there are some existing solutions, have you tried to search?

Comment: Thanks DrTyrsa, yes I have the javascript implementation to add and remove values my issue is to have django automatically handle the new list and update the database. I'm trying to search but haven't found exact solution, I'm still trying to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create form with MultipleChoiceField:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    to_select = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput, choices=[])
```

In this case you have to override form`s save method.

Did you try to create model form for subgroup class?

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=Subgroup
```